# Replace string with .htaccess

Tags: string, .htaccess, url, replace

How can I replace string "#038;" with "&" in a url using htaccess?

Url example: http://www.example.com/page/2/?s=abc#038;post=xyz

I use this cose:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)#038;(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /$%1&%2  [L]
```

but it doesn't works.

:-) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless completely impossible, it would be much better to just fix whatever is generating bad URLs.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why it's impossible? I need to do that 'cause I can't fix it directly in php code.

Comment: You misread me. I said that if at all possible you should fix the code that is creating bad URLs in the first place.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I had misread. So, have you a htaccess solution? For now I can't get my hands on the code.

Answer (score 0):

URL part after `#` is not even sent to the web server so you cannot do this replacement in Apache `mod_rewrite` module.

You can do this in Javascript:

```
location.assign(location.href.replace(/#038;/g, "&"));
```